# Substitute for Len function

Tags: python, function

I am writing a simple search algorithm. Below is my code.

```
def search(list_data,target_char):
    found = False
    position = 0
    while position < len(list_data) and not found:
        if list_data[position] == target_char:
          found = True
        position += 1
    return found
```

However I am not supposed to use the len() or any other built in function. How may I do the same?

Comment: `while True: ... break`? you would also need to manually increment position like you do and a `try - except` block to catch the `IndexError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, you can use `while True` and manually terminate it when you either find what you are looking for or when you exhaust your list.

```
def search(list_data, target_char):
    found = False
    position = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if list_data[position] == target_char:
                found = True
                break
        except IndexError:
            break
        position += 1
    return found

print(search([1, 3, 5], 3))  # prints: True
print(search([1, 3, 5], 'asdas'))  # prints: False
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create the len function by yourself, with something like this:

```
def myLen(tab):
    index = 0
    while(tab != []):
        tab = tab[0:-1]
        index+=1
    return index
```

---

```
a=[1,3,4,5]
print(myLen(a))
```

---